# gpsd daemon differential-gps get heading

Tags: bash, gps, daemon, gpsd

Is it possible to get heading information using gpsd and a differential-gps device?

I'm seeing the raw serial messages with the format below coming though, however on the default gpsd port I'm not seeing any heading values.

Raw serial:

```
$HEHDT,264.69,T*10
```

TCP port:

```
{"class":"TPV","tag":"GGA","device":"/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_USB-RS232_Cable_FTU98S5G-if00-port0","mode":3,"lat":41.408677538,"lon":-132.105521583,"alt":14.460}
```

Looking in the gpsd man pages I don't see any flags which could help decode these strings. Wondering if its even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using a python/command line package called gpsd will decode it for you.
Run `sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps` and it will install that package. Read this manual page by adafruit to help you use it.
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-the-raspberry-pi/setting-everything-up